# How to find which planet contains pops of a specific species?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris (2.3.3), I want to find out on which planet(s) I can find pops of a specific species. If I go into the Species menu and look up the species, it will tell me there are "X pops living on Y planets" but it doesn't tell me which planets these are. I have a huge empire with a ton of different species, so the Planets and Sectors menu is next to useless for this purpose. How can I track down which planet contains pops of a specific species?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new template (gene modification) for the species you're interested in or use an existing one.
2. Click "Apply Template"

You will then be prompted to check, which planets to apply the template to. This shows you a a list of the planets where the species lives. It also shows you how many pops of the species live on each planet.

Just cancel applying the template after you got the information you want.